# get current page url

Tags: google-apps-script

On a web app using GAS HtmlService I need to get the url of current page to build a new link within a template.

The web app will run in a Google sites page (GAS as gadget) but also standalone

I am trying "var pageUrl = document.location.href" and then use pageUrl within a Html template like follow. I know it's wrong, but I am lost, Sorry.

```
<a href="<?= pageUrl + "?item=xyz" ?>" >Item xyz link</a>
```

Thanks, Fausto

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get the url for a webapp via ScriptApp:

```
<a href="<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() + "?item=xyz" ?>" >Item xyz link</a>
```

and you can get the url in sites via SitesApp:

```
SitesApp.getActivePage().getUrl()
```

although I don't think that's actually useful for what you seem to be describing since you can't add useful query parameters to it. Scripts run in iframes, so although you can use document.location on the client, it won't help you anyways. The URL is sanitized and the service id is stripped out.

Comment: is there no way to get the actual Url in both scenarios, like using document.location.href ?

Comment: There is not. The script runs inside an iframe pointed to script.google.com/blank, so the "actual" url you'd get would be that.

Comment: thanks Corey for your support, I will have to look for another approach

Comment: Note this answer is no longer supported by Sites since they changed the interface in 2016.

Answer (score 1):

it works for me:

```
function doGet(e){
  Logger.log(ScriptApp.getService().getUrl());
}
```

then load your web app page and then check the log in your appscript!

Answer (score 0):

Can you afford to go the jQuery route?

```
$(document).ready( function() {

var currentURL = window.location;

$('#myLink').prop('href', currentURL);


});
```

Then...

```
<a id="myLink" href="">Link to somewhere</a>
```

Comment: That won't work... window.location currently points to script.google.com/blank, and the behavior is not guaranteed to remain that way (but I can pretty much guarantee that it won't ever be the url that appears in the browser bar). There are iframes here doing magic that complements what Caja is doing, and the inability to read the window.location without explicit permission granted via ScriptApp is intentional.

Comment: I rather not use jQuery, however I tried something like that and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays (since the Sites change in 2016) the answer is a bit simpler:

```
var current_url = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getUrl();
```